# unable to access account number

Tags: java

```
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;
        import java.util.ArrayList;

        public class AccountOwner {
            private Account account;
            private String firstname;
            private String lastname;
            private String address;
            private double currentBalance;
            private ArrayList<Integer> withdrawAmount = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);
            private ArrayList<Double> deposits = new ArrayList<Double>();
            private ArrayList<Double> purchases = new ArrayList<Double>(5);
            private DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("##0.00"); 

            public AccountOwner(String firstname, String lastname, String address) {
                this.firstname = firstname;
                this.lastname = lastname;
                this.address = address;
            }

            public String getFirstName() {
                return firstname;
            }

            public String getLatName() {
                return lastname;
            }

            public String getAddress() {
                return address;
            }


            public String checkBalance() {

                for (Double deposit : deposits) {
                    this.currentBalance += deposit;
                }

                return formatter.format(currentBalance);
            }

            public void makeDeposit(double amount) {
                deposits.add(amount);
            }

            public void viewAllDeposits() {

                double allDeposits = 0.0;
                System.out.println("All deposits till today:");
                for (int i = 0; i < deposits.size(); i++) {
                    allDeposits = deposits.get(i);

                    System.out.print("\t"+"$"+allDeposits);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

            public void withdrawMoney(int amount) {
                withdrawAmount.add(amount);
                currentBalance -= amount;
            }

            public String getActualBalance() {
                return formatter.format(currentBalance);
            }

            public void withdrawAmounts(){
                System.out.println("All Withdrawls till today");
                for(int i = 0; i < withdrawAmount.size(); i++){
                    System.out.print("\t"+"$"+withdrawAmount.get(i));
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

            public void makePurchase(double itemPrice){
                purchases.add(itemPrice);
                this.currentBalance -= itemPrice;
            }

            public void viewAllmadePurchases() {

                double purchase = 0.0;
                System.out.println("All purchases made till today:");
                for (int i = 0; i < purchases.size(); i++) {
                    purchase = purchases.get(i);

                    System.out.print("\t"+"$"+purchase);
                }

            }

            public void viewMyPersonalInformation(){
                System.out.println("Firstname:" + this.firstname);
                System.out.println("LastName:" +this.lastname);
                System.out.println("Address:" +this.address);
                System.out.println("Balance:" +this.checkBalance());
                viewAllDeposits();
                withdrawAmounts();
                viewAllmadePurchases();

            }



        public class Account {
            private AccountOwner customer;
            private int accountNumber;


            public Account(){
                customer = null;
                accountNumber = 0000000;


            }

            public Account(int accountNumber, AccountOwner owner){
                       this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
                       customer = owner;


            }

            public int accountNumberIs(){
                return accountNumber;
            }

        public class BankManager {
            private Account account;
            private AccountOwner accountOwner;
            private int accountNumber;


                public void createNewAccount(int accountNumber, AccountOwner owner){
                account = new Account(accountNumber, owner);
                this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
                this.accountOwner = owner;
                }



            public int getaccountNumber(){

                return accountNumber;
            }


            public void setAccountNumber(int newaccountnumber){
                accountNumber = newaccountnumber;
            }

            public void customerInformation(){
                accountOwner.viewMyPersonalInformation();
            }
public class MainProgram {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BankManager manager = new BankManager();
        AccountOwner owner = new AccountOwner("Tom", "Smith", "208 W 119th St");
        manager.createNewAccount(389745, owner);
        Account acc = new Account();





        owner.makeDeposit(550);
        owner.makeDeposit(700);
        owner.makeDeposit(122.93);
        owner.makeDeposit(195.93);
        owner.withdrawMoney(200);
        owner.makePurchase(200);
        owner.makeDeposit(100);
        owner.makePurchase(1220);
        owner.withdrawMoney(30);



        owner.viewMyPersonalInformation();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(acc.accountNumberIs());
```

The problem that i have is i'm trying to access the account number from the accountowner without involving a reference to the bankmanager class.. how can i get it to work. I have
been trying to using the account class itself cause i created a constructor and assign those
paramaters to the fields in the account class but seems not to work

Answer (score 1):

This code contains a bug :

```
public Account(int accountNumber, AccountOwner owner){
    AccountOwner cstomer = owner;
    int acctNumber = accountNumber;
    accountNumber = acctNumber;
    //System.out.println(accountNumber);
}
```

The `accountNumber` parameter you're passing into your constructor is taking precedence over your class's `accountNumber` field.  your `Account`'s `accountNumber` field is never actually getting set.

This is equivalent to :

```
public Account(int accountNumber, AccountOwner owner){
    AccountOwner cstomer = owner;
    accountNumber = accountNumber;
}
```

---

to make sure that you're accessing the field use the `this` keyword as in: `this.accountNumber`

```
public Account(int accountNumber, AccountOwner owner){
    AccountOwner cstomer = owner;
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    //System.out.println(accountNumber);
}
```

There is another bug, the `Account.customer` is not assigned :

```
public Account(int accountNumber, AccountOwner owner){
    customer = owner;
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
}
```

I recommend you to learn to use a debugger or still better write unit tests (first).

Comment: I'll +1  if you more clearly explain what was going wrong with the OP's code, and why your code will fix it.

Comment: ok this is what is going on.. when i try to get the account number from the account class i get  0 instead of the actual account number..

Comment: There is another bug, i think the last code sample works. I hope there  isn't another bug.

Answer (score 0):

```
class AccountOwner {
//...
    private Account account;
//...
    public Integer getAccountNumber() {
        return this.account != null ? this.account.accountNumberIs() : null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set your accountNumber type to be **int** and set it to 0000000 (*which is equal to just 0 for an int type*) therefore you are getting 0 when you call getAccountNumber() method.

Instead, change accountNumber type to **String** and initialize it to '0000000'. You will see 0000000 being printed then.